# Como leer y mostrar datos de una tarjeta nfc?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nfc

Hola estoy tratado de leer el contenido de una tarjeta `nfc` pero no he podido saber de que me lea y me muestre el contenido, probé unos ejemplos pero me es confuso solo quiero que me lo muestre en el `toast`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });



    NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
    NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"nfc Activo",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"nfc desactivado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



}

private void  write(Ndef ndef) throws IOException, FormatException{

    ndef.connect();
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getNdefMessage();
    String message = new String(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload());
    ndef.close();


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Simplemente activa NFC en tu dispositivo pero debes saber que no todos los dispositivos pueden soportar esta característica, agrego respuesta, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

**Lo que tienes que realizar para compartir/recibir información NFC es simplemente permitir el intercambio de datos desde tu dispositivo.**

**Es importante saber que no todos los dispositivos tienen soporte para NFC, por esta razón te recomiendo realizar una validación.**

Primeramente agrega la caracteristica en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` (`true` si es estrictamente necesario su uso en la aplicación):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />
```

Determina si tu dispositivo soporta NFC, en caso de tener soporte y estar desactivado puedes mostrar automáticamente la configuración para que el usuario la active :

```
if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Este dispositivo NO soporta NFC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{

    if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NFC Activado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NFC desactivado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Si se encuentra desactivado, abre configuración!
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));

    }

}
```